# How To Create a Custom List of ProgressBars in .Net 2.0

Tags: winforms, listview, user-controls, .net-2.0, progress-bar

I have created a progress bar custom control and would like to embed this into a list which can be sorted and placed on a windows form using .Net 2.0.
What is the best approach for this?

Is it possible to just add it to a ListView as a subitem?  Is there a better way to achieve this?  I want it to be as lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not a ListView but [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2) is an unsupported progress bar cell/column sample based on [DataGridViewImageCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecell.aspx) class.